# IndexError: index 50552 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50552

Tags: python, index-error

I'm trying to run predicted_labels:

```
def test_ensemble_labels(train_data, y, test_data, vector_names, NNeighbours, lower, upper):
    y_pred = []
    for j in range(len(vector_names)):
        y_pred.append(frnn_owa_method(train_data, y, test_data, vector_names[j], NNeighbours[j], lower, upper)[1])
    # Use voting function to obtain the ensembled label - we used mean
    y_pred_res = np.mean(y_pred, axis=0)
    return y_pred_res 

predicted_labels = test_ensemble_labels(train_data, data['Label'], test_data, ["Vector_d2v"], [19], additive(), additive())
```

But I get an error:

```
4 frames
/content/frlearn/neighbours/classifiers.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     24     def construct(self, X, y) -> Model:
     25         model: FuzzyRoughEnsemble.Model = super().construct(X, y)
---> 26         Cs = [X[np.where(y == c)] for c in model.classes]
     27         model.upper_approximations = self.upper_approximator and [self.upper_approximator.construct(C) for C in Cs]
     28         co_Cs = [X[np.where(y != c)] for c in model.classes]
```

**[image: IndexError: index 50552 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50552]**

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please tell the shapes of `X`, `y`, `model.classes` ?

Comment: shape of y= (50552, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the loop like this

```py
for j in range(len(vector_names) - 1):
    # [..Your stuff...]
```

Comment: Does the answer helped?